# construct an object into another object

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

this should be a stupid problem but i dont know where to start,so i'll ask here.i've got a class named Routing which is binded to a datagrid. Inside this class theres an object from another class:

```
 public class Routing : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public int Sequenza { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<Prodotti> availableProducts;
    public ObservableCollection<Prodotti> AvailableProducts
    {
        get { return availableProducts; }
        set
        {
            if (availableProducts != value)
            {
                availableProducts = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AvailableProducts");
            }
        }
    }
    private Prodotti product;
    public Prodotti Product
    {
        get { return product; }
        set
        {
            if (product != value)
            {
                product = value;
                UpdateAvailableCosts();
                OnPropertyChanged("Product");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then the Product class:

```
public class Prodotti
{
    public int Product_id { get; set; }
    public string Product_description { get; set; }
    public int Product_treshold { get; set; }
}
```

Everything works as intended,and if i just declare the "Sequenza = 1" in the routing the datagrid adds the 1 in the first row/column. But i would like to add more initial values,maybe based on data present in the database. but i cant come up with the constructor for it

```
Routes.Add(new Routing { Sequenza = 1,Prodotti=... });
```

Comment: _Routes.Add(new Routing () { Sequenza = 1,product = new Prodotti(), ... });_

Comment: yea this one worked. i had to declare it as new. Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure that you don't need a List<Prodotto> here? something is not clear here (In italian _Prodotti_ is the plural form of _Prodotto_)

Comment: well it works as intended,and i dont see any side effect to it really. i use ObservableCollection. i know italian dont worry haha

Answer (score 2):

```
Routes.Add(new Routing { Sequenza = 1,Prodotti= new Prodotti{Product_id =1, Product_description  = "str", Product_treshold =1} });
```